# Contact Form Parent Link Cannot Be Set

Tags: emails

I enabled the contact form menu link, and then attempted to change the parent link to the Main Menu. However, instead of making the parent link < Main Menu >, I accidentally made the parent link Main Menu under < Management >. Now I am now unable to set the parent link for the contact form.

However, I can see the contact form's position in the parent link drop down menu when that menu is accessed using +Add Link in Structure > Menus > Main Menu. Here's what I see (with some lines omitted).

--Administration

----Structure

------Menus

--------Main Menu

----------Contact (disabled)

When I look at all of my options under Structure > Menus in the Adminstration tools, nowhere am I given an option to enable and change the contact form menu link.

I've tried disabling and reenabling the Contact module, logging out and logging back in, and flushing all caches. None of that helped. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I think you should uninstall the Contact module, flush the cache and then reinstall that module.

Comment: Uninstall, flush, reinstall didn't reset the parent link for the contact form. But I found and corrected the contact menu parent link in Structure > Menus > Management > List Links. Not sure whether I overlooked it or couldn't access it prior to reinstall. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please don't edit an answer into a question. You can answer your own question, or, if there still is a time limit, post in a comment noting you will make it an answer when possible.